# Android not finishing activity when told to

Tags: android

I have a scenario where the user can either click on the back button to access the previous activity *or* do whatever else and the activity will end itself (such as an incoming call, click on the power button, switch app...). These calls must return different results to the previous activity (called with `startActivityForResult`), it's either a graceful quit or a messy one according to which actions will be taken...

Now when Android calls `onBackPressed` it will always also call `onStop` too, not the other way round though. So I'd like for my app to finish when I call `onBackPressed` without calling `onStop`, calling `finish()` inside `onBackPressed` doesn't work.

Some code to illustrate my problem:

```
@Override
public void onStop() {
    // this gets called no matter what, I don't like that
    Log.i(TAG, "Canceled");
    setResult(RESULT_CANCELED, new Intent());
    finish();
    super.onStop();
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Log.i(TAG, "User ended activity");
    setResult(RESULT_OK, new Intent());
    finish();
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to call `setResult()` repeatedly as the app closes use [Activity.isFinsihing()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#isFinishing%28%29):

```
@Override
public void onStop() {
    // Now this is only called if Activity is not finishing already
    if(!isFinishing()) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Canceled");
        setResult(RESULT_CANCELED, new Intent());
        finish();
    }
    super.onStop();
}
```